# AX1650 Wi-Fi card makes Wi-Fi router disconnect all users

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router, connection, wifi-driver

My home Wi-Fi router keeps disconnecting all users including my laptop every 5-15 minutes. This only happens when my laptop is connected to Wi-Fi. My laptop is a Dell XPS 7590 with Killer AX1650 Wi-Fi running Windows 10 Home. I have another laptop with a Killer 1550 also running Windows 10 Home that does NOT do the same.

Comment: Do you have original WPA (TKIP) enabled in any way? If so, switch to pure WPA2 (AES-CCMP) only.

Comment: How do these coexist: On the one hand "keeps disconnecting all users" and then "does NOT do the same".

Comment: @harrymc `another laptop with a killer 1550`

Comment: @TomYan: I understood "users" as "network users/computers".

Comment: @Spiff It's been a couple of hours with no discconection, I changed it from TKIP & AES to AES only. Looks like it's gonna work, I just wonder how do you know that this was the problem? And how does TKIP pose the problem in the first place?

Comment: I'll post this as an Answer with a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the wireless security settings of your AP (wireless router), if you have original WPA (TKIP) enabled in any way, disable it so that you are using WPA2 (AES-CCMP) **only**.

Original WPA was always kind of a kludge to patch up WEP's weaknesses without requiring new cryptographic hardware. One of original WPA's defenses against attacks was to kick everyone off the network for 60 seconds if an attack attempt was detected. Unfortunately, buggy clients could send malformed packets that were indistinguishable from attacks, so a buggy client can cause the whole network to drop for 60 seconds at a time. If you have original WPA available as an option, it means all multicast and broadcast packets must use original WPA because that's the "lowest common denominator" among your clients. So any client with a buggy implementation of original WPA can cause your whole network to drop for 60 seconds at a time.

Comment: Yeah that definitely worked! Thanks for the explanation, delighted to understand!